# Centering an image as a link within a div

Tags: html, css

## Easy problem: Centering an `img` within a `div`:

I have `div` with a given width and height, and an `img` with an unknown width and height within the `div`:

```
<style>
    div {
        width: ...;
        height: ...;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <img src="...">
</div>
```

Centering the `img` while keeping it contained is easy:

```
div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Here's a couple examples of centering a 500x300 `img` using this approach:

- In a 400x200 `div`: https://jsfiddle.net/thejonwithnoh/f9evLpx0/
- In a 200x400 `div`: https://jsfiddle.net/thejonwithnoh/9dndr9r8/

## Hard problem: Centering an `img` within an `a` within a `div`

I have `div` with a given width and height, and an `img` with an unknown width and height within an `a` within the `div` :

```
<style>
    div {
        width: ...;
        height: ...;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <a href="...">
        <img src="...">
    </a>
</div>
```

A solution which gets pretty close is simply to style the `a` as such:

```
a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Here's a couple examples of centering a 500x300 `img` using this approach:

- In an `a` in a 400x200 `div`: https://jsfiddle.net/thejonwithnoh/udo957d9/
- In an `a` in a 200x400 `div`: https://jsfiddle.net/thejonwithnoh/k0nj571f/

The problem here is that the space outside of the `img` but within the `div` is now clickable as a link.

## The question (tl;dr friendly)

How can I center an `img` (of unknown size) within a `div` (of known size), but also have the image be a link?

## Edit for clarifications/requirements based on comments:

- The answer should only be in html and css (i.e. no javascript)
- The answer should not depend on any framework (though framework dependent answers are still interesting in their own right, and I would be curious to see them, but they are not allowed for the "accepted" answer)
- The image should maintain its aspect ratio
- The image should be contained by the div

  - If the image is bigger than the div in either dimension, then the image should be scaled so that it fits that dimension
  - Otherwise, if the image is not bigger than the div in either dimension, then the image should simply be its natural size centered within the div (though I'd be curious to see a solution where the image is scaled up to snugly fit within the div, but they are not allowed for the "accepted" answer)
- The area outside the image and inside the div should not be part of the link

Comment: Boostrap using ?

Comment: @BashaHameed I'd prefer the answer to be independent of bootstrap or any frameworks, but if there is an answer that uses bootstrap, it'd be nice to know as well.

Comment: instead of `<div>`, why don't you try `<p>`. See [here](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/bYKLwW)

Comment: In both examples you've tried, just remove the height and width properties from the anchor element.

Comment: @SunnySidhu Indeed...that seems ideal.

Comment: @SunnySidhu but then the image no longer maintains it's aspect ratio in the 400x200 example

Comment: @thejonwithnoh Sorry, in that particular one, remove only the width.

Comment: There is a JS solution if you want?

Comment: @SunnySidhu while the image still looks correct in both cases, the problem is now in the 200x400 case, the area above and below the image is still clickable as a link

Comment: @Maverick thanks, but I'm trying to do it only in html and css if possible

Comment: @DhavalJardosh You've specified the image size in your codepen, but I need the let the image size remain unknown.  It should get as big as possible without going outside the div.

Comment: @thejonwithnoh, and the div will always be greater than the img, right?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh That cannot be assumed.  The image size is completely unknown.

Comment: @thejonwithnoh, Then there are chances that image will overflow. If the image is bigger

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Exactly, and I'm looking for a solution to that problem.  Centering the image is not the difficult problem.  The problem is making the link behave correctly too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way for centering an `image` (even it is wrapped by `<a></a>`) within a fixed width/height `div` container is this:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;      
  font-size: 0px;
  background-color:red;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
   max-width:100%;
   max-height:100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/></a>
</div>
```

Setting the `div`s' ...
- `line-height` equal to its `height` combined with an `image` that has `vertical-align` set to `center`, centers the image vertically. 
- `text-align` to `center`, centers the image horizontally.

Comment: I think this might be it!... I'll do some rigorous testing and either let you know where it breaks, or accept the answer :-)

Comment: Glad I could help you! :)

Comment: It's sooo close, but there's one weird issue... it seems that when I change the height (and line-height of course) to 100px, then the image is ever so slightly sneaking out the bottom of the div (at least in chrome and firefox)... any thoughts? https://jsfiddle.net/thejonwithnoh/1cfj1j3b/

Comment: @thejonwithnoh remove the vertical-align

Comment: @Maverick but then if i switch the height (and line-height) back to 150px, then it's no longer vertically centered ;-)

Comment: @thejonwithnoh I know :( Welcome to the web

Comment: Oh, I see. There is an issue with setting the `line-height` to a fixed value. Try using: `line-height:100%;`

Comment: @oRole It will work for this issue but not when the height is bigger :(

Comment: @oRole hmm... doesn't seem to work when I increase my height again

Comment: @thejonwithnoh Just hack it `img { margin-top: -2px; }`

Comment: @Maverick: It's definitely tempting, but the -2px magic number doesn't seem to work on firefox (though -3px seems to work)... either way, I'm curious why this slight offset is happening anyway

Comment: @oRole looks like the percentage didn't work for line-height because it's a percentage of the font-size, not the height... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#<percentage>

Comment: @oRole but then that got me thinking... what if we left height = line-height, but set font-size to 0... and it worked! https://jsfiddle.net/thejonwithnoh/1cfj1j3b/1/ ... so I think this might be the answer if you update it! but once again, I just want to do more testing before I accept...

Comment: @thejonwithnoh Yup! You are right. Used that piece of code a couple of times, but never faced that issue. I'll update the answer.